# How to read data from template table to controller class in thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am new to thyemleaf , I need some basic code to read html table data ( which was constructed in ArrayList ) to controller class

Consider below is the th: each block

```
<tr class="table-row"  th:each="account, itemStat : ${accountentry}">
                <td class="table-data" th:text="${itemStat.count}"></td>
                <td class="table-data" th:text="${account.accountnumber}"></td>
                <td class="table-data" th:text="${account.field1}"></td>
                <td class="table-data" th:text="${account.field2}"></td>
</tr>
```

How to pass above data to controller class 
I already posted

I already asked similar question([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082577/how-to-bind-table-data-with-arraylist-from-thymeleaf-to-controller-class))  since no response yet going back to basics.
Appreciated for your help in advance,thanks.

Comment: This question is just too broad.  If you have some specific question, we can help with that -- until then, I suggest reading tutorials on creating forms with thymeleaf: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form

Comment: @Metroids I posted my specific question over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082577/how-to-bind-table-data-with-arraylist-from-thymeleaf-to-controller-class

Comment: @Metroids bit disappoint you marked -1 I was given link of my previous question which is elaborated since I dont want to confuse I asked in separate ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from here [Thymeleaf form submit with ArrayList Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119063/thymeleaf-form-submit-with-arraylist-object)

Please refer above link of my similar question and answer for someone who is searching solution like me