# Thymeleaf form submit with ArrayList Object

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have written a simple program for form submit with the data(ArrayList) to send from table to controller class.

While submitting the form the data is always empty not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am almost spending a lot of time to identify the issue no luck :(

**Controller Class** ( Where I always getting null in Post method )

```
public class AccountContoller {

private ArrayList<AccountwithSelection> allAccountwithSelect = new ArrayList<AccountwithSelection>();
public AccountContoller()
{
    //Written some test data in Array
    AccountwithSelection accountwithSelection1 =  new AccountwithSelection();
    accountwithSelection1.setAccountnumber("Acct1");
    accountwithSelection1.setIlc("ILC1");
    allAccountwithSelect.add(accountwithSelection1);
    AccountwithSelection accountwithSelection2 =  new AccountwithSelection();
    accountwithSelection2.setAccountnumber("Acct2");
    accountwithSelection1.setIlc("ILC2");
    allAccountwithSelect.add(accountwithSelection2);

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/accountload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   String accountload(Model model) {
      AccountSelectionListWrapper wrapper = new AccountSelectionListWrapper();
      wrapper.setAccountList(allAccountwithSelect);
      model.addAttribute("accountload", wrapper);
      return "accountload";
   }

@RequestMapping(value = "/accountload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addimeiPost(Model model,
        @ModelAttribute("accountload") AccountSelectionListWrapper wrapper,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
     System.out.println(wrapper.getAccountList()); //Always getting null, why ?
    return "accountload";

}
```

}

**Class: AccountwithSelection**

```
public class AccountwithSelection {
public String accountnumber, ilc;

public String getAccountnumber() {
    return accountnumber;
}

public void setAccountnumber(String accountnumber) {
    this.accountnumber = accountnumber;
}

public String getIlc() {
    return ilc;
}

public void setIlc(String ilc) {
    this.ilc = ilc;
}

}
```

**WrapperClass- AccountSelectionListWrapper**

```
public class AccountSelectionListWrapper {

public ArrayList<AccountwithSelection> accountList;

public ArrayList<AccountwithSelection> getAccountList() {
    return accountList;
}

public void setAccountList(ArrayList<AccountwithSelection> accountList) {
    this.accountList = accountList;
}

}
```

**HTML Form:**(accountload.html)

```
    <form action="#" th:action="accountload" th:object="${accountload}" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=form-group-1>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Data" name="action">
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="mytable" class="table">
        <tbody class="table-tbody" style="width: 90%">
            <tr class="table-head">
                <th>ACCOUNT NUMBER</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table-row">
            <tr class="table-row" th:each="account, stat : *{accountList}">
                <td class="table-data" th:text="${account.getAccountnumber()}"
                    th:field="*{accountList[__${stat.index}__].accountnumber}"
                    th:value="${account.getAccountnumber()}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<td />` elements aren't submitted with a form.  You need to use some kind of input.  It should look something like this:

```
<td class="table-data">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{accountList[__${stat.index}__].accountnumber}" />
</td>
```

or if you want to submit without seeing the fields as editable, something like this

```
<td class="table-data">
  <span th:text="${account.accountnumber}" />
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{accountList[__${stat.index}__].accountnumber}" />
</td>
```

Comment: could you please have a look at this thread with similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582080/thymeleaf-form-submit-with-model-having-associations